# Physical interpretation of Poisson's equation and Dirichlet problem

Tags: potential-theory, greens-function, poissons-equation

I am a mathematics student trying to understand physics behind the Poisson equation and the Dirichlet problem. We know that the electric potential potential $u$ satisfies the Poisson Equation:

$\Delta u= -\rho$ (up to a constant)

where $\rho$ is the charge density of some total charge Q contained in some body (i.e. region) $\Omega$.

I guess the potential is some abstract quantity defined at any point in space, could be both outside or inside the body. The density is obviously zero outside the body, so for regions with no charge we have the Laplace equation:

$\Delta u = 0$

Moreover, for a body in electrostatic equilibrium, we know 2 things:

1) it has constant potential inside

2) and all of the charge is located on the boundary

Questions:

1) How is the Dirichlet's problem related to all this? I initially thought that since there is no charge inside the body, we have $\Delta u = 0$ on $\Omega$, but it is not clear to me how we can get $u = f$ on $\partial \Omega$ and what should f be. Clearly f is not equal to the value of potential on $\partial \Omega$ which is constant on the surface. Then what is f?

2) If for any body the density is $\textbf{always}$ zero inside and outside the body, then the Poisson equation for the potential always reduces to Laplace equation inside or outside the body. $\rho$ is only non-zero on the boundary. Then where do we encounter the Poisson equation as it is, with $\Delta u(x) = g(x)$ for $x\in \Omega$, not $x\in\partial\Omega$?

References for books are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In electrostatics, the gradient of the potential is proportional to the electric field, which is a physical quantity.  Physicists model charge density in distinct ways that include (i) volume charge, (ii) surface charge, (iii) line charge, (iv) point charge, (v) dipole layers.  Therefore, one can have $\nabla^2 \Phi=0$ inside and outside a domain, but with a surface charge layer (or dipole surface layer) on the boundary.  This happens on the surface of a "perfect" conductor for which the potential is constant on the boundary.

Comment: @Dr.MV So my assumption that the charge is always zero both inside and outside is only true for perfect conductors, and for non-perfect conductors we can have continuous charge density that could be non-zero inside the body?

Comment: We can have a variety of charge distributions, both inside and outside any designated domain.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on Newtonial potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_potential) addresses the electrostatic potential of a charged body at the end: the function $u$ is a *single layer potential*.  It satisfies the Laplace equation both in the interior (trivially, by being constant) and in the exterior  (which is of interest). So, one usually considers this as a *Dirichlet problem in the exterior domain*, that is in $G = \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \overline{\Omega}$. So the problem is then to find a harmonic function in $G$ that is equal to a constant $C$ on the boundary $\partial G$ and tends to $0$ at infinity. (This is for three and more dimensions; in two dimensions the potential must have logarithmic growth at infinity instead of decay.) The value of $C$ depends on how much charge is put on the body $\Omega$; it is basically charge divided by the capacity of $\Omega$.

The Poisson equation models a charge distributed across some three-dimensional region. I imagine it as charged dust particles suspended in the air, which perhaps doesn't happen often (search for "3d charge density" or "volume charge density" comes up mostly with textbook exercises). But it has a natural interpretation as the gravitational  potential  of a gas cloud.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You mentioned that 3-dimensional continuous charge distribution does not happen very often. Could you please tell me, in what cases can we have a solid body with continuous charge distribution over the whole volume, not only on on the boundary? Is it the case for a charged non-perfect conductor? And for perfect ones, it is always on the boundary?

Comment: Yes and yes, but this really is more of a physics question. Examples: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251340 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39369 (concerning non-conductors); http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186553 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232447 (concerning ideal conductors).